# XSLT - Remove duplicates from mapped results

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

This isn't quite the threads on removing duplicates I've found on this forum.

I have a key/value map and I want to remove duplicates from the final results of the mapping.

Source Document:

```
<article>
    <subject code="T020-060"/>
    <subject code="T020-010"/>
    <subject code="T090"/>
</article>
```

Mapping:

```
<xsl:variable name="topicalMap">
    <topic MapCode="T020-060">Value 1</topic>
    <topic MapCode="T020-010">Value 1</topic>
    <topic MapCode="T090">Value 3</topic>
</xsl:variable>
```

Desired Result:

```
<article>
    <topic>Value 1</topic>
    <topic>Value 3</topic>
</article>
```

XSLT I'm working with (note, it has a testing tags and code to make sure the mapping works):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf8" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"/>

<xsl:template match="article">
    <article>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="subject" group-by="$topicalMap/topic[@MapCode = @code]">
            <test-group>
                <code>Current code: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></code>
                <topic>Current keyword: <xsl:value-of
                        select="$topicalMap/topic[@MapCode = @code]"/></topic>
            </test-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <simple-mapping><xsl:apply-templates/></simple-mapping>
    </article>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Simple Mapping Topics -->
<xsl:template match="subject">
    <xsl:variable name="ArticleCode" select="@code"/>
    <topic>
        <xsl:value-of select="$topicalMap/topic[@MapCode = $ArticleCode]"/>
    </topic>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Keyword Map -->
<xsl:variable name="topicalMap">
    <topic MapCode="T020-060">Value 1</topic>
    <topic MapCode="T020-010">Value 1</topic>
    <topic MapCode="T090">Value 3</topic>
</xsl:variable>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Doing the group-by that way produces nothing. If I duplicate the topics in the source document and do group-by="@code" that works to remove before applying the mapping. But I want to remove resultant duplicate values not duplicate keys.

Simple-mapping stuff is just to show working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="subject" group-by="$topicalMap/topic[@MapCode = current()/@code]">
        <topic>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </topic>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

or better yet

```
<xsl:key name="map" match="topic" use="@MapCode"/>


<xsl:template match="article">
    <article>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="subject" group-by="key('map', @code, $topicalMap)">
            <topic>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            </topic>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </article>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using key() that makes it better?

Comment: Given the `<xsl:key name="map" match="topic" use="@MapCode"/>` the processor indexes the `topic` elements by the `MapCode` attribute value and then with repeated access finds a match directly by using the index instead of searching through all elements.